# Extract <td> Elements using BS4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to go through a website and extract some information using Chromedriver. The problem that I have when I use BeautifulSoup is that I can't find a way to extract table inside a `class`.

The way I am trying to extract the information looks like this:

```
results = soup.find_all("div", class_="widget widgetLarge fpPerfglissanteclassique")
```

Is there a way to change this line so that it will only return the Information in `<td>...</td>` that can be found **inside** the class?!

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `results` variable contains another BeautifulSoup object (ResultSet) which you can iterate though and call `find` and `find_all` on the individual result items.

Like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="widget widgetLarge fpPerfglissanteclassique">
    <td>item 1</td>
    <td>item 2</td>
    <td>item 3</td>
</div>
<div class="widget widgetLarge fpPerfglissanteclassique">
    <td>item 4</td>
    <td>item 5</td>
    <td>item 6</td>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
results = soup.find_all("div", class_="widget widgetLarge fpPerfglissanteclassique")

for result in results:
    table_results = result.find_all("td")
    print(table_results)
```

Result:

```
[<td>item 1</td>, <td>item 2</td>, <td>item 3</td>]
[<td>item 4</td>, <td>item 5</td>, <td>item 6</td>]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the table is inside this class, you can use this example how to get data from it:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="widget widgetLarge fpPerfglissanteclassique">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

results = soup.find_all(
    "div", class_="widget widgetLarge fpPerfglissanteclassique"
)

for result in results:  # <-- iterate every result
    for row in result.find_all("tr"):  # <-- find all rows
        cell_data = []
        for cell in row.find_all("td"):  # <-- find all cells inside row
            cell_data.append(cell.text)
        print(*cell_data)
```

Prints:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```